# Centralized change of resolution in Windows

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-7

How can I change the screen resolution of several Windows 7 machines from a central point, i.e., a server running Active Directory?

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that? The screen resolution is an individual  machine-specific setting that each client should handle by itself to fit the display attached.

Comment: I'm curious. Do you have an actual technical reason to do this or do you just want to annoy your users?

Answer (score 1):

Typically this would be achieved by group policies for the machines in question. However none such policy exists as overriding screen resolution remotely is typically Not a Good Idea (TM).

Instead you should configure the screen resolutions manually, although the best resolution should be selected by Windows automatically when you install the appropriate drivers.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a Startup script for all your users in your AD (under their `Profile` tab in the `Logon script` field) and have that call a tool like [QRes](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Other-VIDEO-Tools/QRes.shtml) to set their resolution. A simple batch file would do the trick, like

```
C:\ServerScripts\QRes.exe /x:1280 /y:1024
```